# Visual Studio Code language extension not highlighting syntax

Tags: visual-studio-code, textmate, vscode-extensions

Followed [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_adding-a-new-language-colorizer) piece of instruction to create a language extension for .abcd files.

During yeoman generator I used [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/textmate/ada.tmbundle/master/Syntaxes/Ada.plist) as a reference.

Everything went well and the new extension was created. Then I open the generated folder as a Visual Studio project and hit **`F5`** to run VS Code with my newly created extension, but nothing gets highlighted as if there is no support for that language.

I have not done any changes to the generated files, but since I am using Ada.plist as a starting point, shouldn't it at least highlight .abcd file as Ada file?

Answer (score 0):

You need package.json file to register the language. It's described in [the same document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_add-to-your-language-support-extension).

You may be interested in this repo also:
https://github.com/Entomy/Ada-vscode

Comment: Isn't that link referring to adding the language into actual VS Code environment instead of having it in debug/dev env.? I saw that extension, but my .abcd language is similar to ada but not exactly ada.